# mean stack and multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm using yo and the meanjs generator to create some basic crud stuff.  That's all pretty easy.

But what i want to do now is create a **relationship** between **2 models**.  so i created all the crud for dog breeds.  i then want to be able to create dogs by selecting the breed from a bootstrap dropdown.  I did the yo crud stuff to get all of the files i need for dogs, i then edited the model to include an `ObjectId` with `ref: breed`.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to populate the breed drop down on the create dog page.

I'm pretty sure that if i can get this working that my next question will be how do i save the breed object into the dog model?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the latest i have, which doesn't do anything

```
<section ng-controller="DogsController">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>New Dog</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form name="dogForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="create(dogForm.$valid)" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" show-errors>


          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-ng-controller="BreedsController" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Dropdown
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li ng-repeat="breed in breeds"><a ng-model="dog.breed">{{breeed.name}}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: just added code to original question

Answer (score 0):

You put your `data-ng-controller="BreedsController"` in the button tag.

Comment: i've tried moving it up to the dropdown div and down to the ul and even the li tags but it still doesn't work.  also, when i inspect it i always see the following where the <li> should be.   <!-- ngRepeat: brewery in breweries -->

Comment: Now I'm really confused, are you listing breeds or breweries. Regardless, if you move the ng-controller and change `{{breeed.name}}` to `{{breed.name}}` you should be good to go. If you still have problems check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/L9WoENrgEgYnqbSFegkw).

Comment: sorry, copy/pasted from the wrong project.  I did fix the typo and my html looks exactly like yours.  I see that your js is all in one file and saving everything directly into $scope.  I've got all of the scaffolding from the yo meanjs generator and all of my breeds are persisted in mongo.  Could this possibly be a path issue based on the fact that i'm in the Dogs module and need to reference the controller that lives over in the Breeds module?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Can you put more of your code in?